# Navigating between page objects correctly in Protractor with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, automated-tests, pageobjects

I'm attempting to get a protractor test suite off the ground with TypeScript and I'm having an issue with the chaining of pageObjects that I'm unsure how to solve or do in a better way.  Any example I've seen never deals with multiple pages.

I'll simplify example files for ease of assisting, the issue seems to centre around when I instantiate the new page object but I'm unsure how to do this in a better way.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

**basePageObject.ts**

```
import { browser, by, element, ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';
import {NextPageObject} from './nextPageObject';

export class BasePage {

async navigateTo() {
 await browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
}

async launchThing() {
 await element(by.css('#launchThing')).click();
}

async clickNavToNextPage(): Promise<NextPageObject> {
 await element(by.css('#nextPageNav')).click();
 return new NextPageObject();
}
}
```

**nextPageObject.ts**

```
import { browser, by, element, ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';

export class NextPageObject {

private firstNameField = element(by.css('.testFirstName'));

async getFirstName(): Promise<string> {
 return await this.firstNameField.getAttribute("value");
}

async enterFirstName(firstName: string): Promise<NextPageObject> {
 await this.firstNameField.clear();
 await this.firstNameField.sendKeys(firstName);
}

}
```

**testSpec.ts**

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
import { BasePage } from 'basePageObject';

const expectedName = "Peter";

fdescribe('Navigation with custom URL', function() {
let page: BasePage;

beforeEach(async () => {
 page = new BasePage();
 await page.navigateTo();
});

fit('page nav', async function() {
 await page.navigateTo(url);

 const next1 = await page.clickNavToNextPage();
 expect(element(by.css('body > next-page- 
 header')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

 await next1.enterFirstName("Peter");

 // this fails as an empty string is returned but is close to the way 
 //I want to do things
 const firstNameFieldValue = await next1.getFirstName();
 expect(await firstNameFieldValue).toEqual(expectedName);


 // this works but is not how I want to do it
 const elementval = element(by.css('.testFirstName'));
 expect(elementval.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(expectedName);

}
}
```

Comment: next1 here is essentially an object of type nextPageObject.  

My issue as I understand it is that I'm then dealing with the state at that point, so firstname getter will always return empty, as it's not evaluating when the getter is actually called.

Comment: I’m not 100% but I think that `firstNameField` should not be a property.  Make it a getter or a `getFirstNameField` method so that it grabs the field when you want to test it.  Right now it is grabbing the field when you construct the page object.  Then, later, when you call `getAttribute` I think it is returning the value at the time the page object was created (before you sent the keys).

Comment: I don't what your `clickNavToNextPage` is, specifically I'm looking to see what it returns

Comment: yes I agree on the problem @Pace but I am using a getter?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov sorry I've hacked together the above to be a simplified version of what I'm dealing with.  It returns a newly initialized page object that I want, I'll edit the code

Comment: I woudn't declare the functions in the page object as async functions. I would make them return promises and use wait in the test case instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
private firstNameField = element(by.css('.testFirstName'));
```

To:

```
private get firstNameField() { return element(by.css('.testFirstName')); }
```

In the first version `element()` is invoked before you send the keys.  In the second version it is invoked after you send the keys.

Comment: thank you @Pace I'll give this a try and report back